# background css update via jquery is not happening

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code pen. I am trying to create a volume controller for html5 audio and I want the image to change corresponding to where the slider is positioned. For example, if the volume is full I want this image:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg/500px-Speaker_Icon.svg.png

But when it is at low volume I want the image to be this instead:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMIyl.png

I feel like my code should we working as intended, I do not know if it is something to do with codepen or if I am just making a silly mistake that is hard to spot.

This is what I have come up with:
https://codepen.io/cryptodescriptor/pen/ErEbzp

I appreciate any help I can get.

A quick overview of the code:

```
  slider.oninput = function() {
    if (this.value >= 66 && !$vol_icon.hasClass('high')) {
      console.log(3);
      updateVolImage(2, 'high');
    } else if (this.value < 66 && this.value >= 33 && !$vol_icon.hasClass('medium')) {
      console.log(2);
      updateVolImage(1, 'medium');
    } else if (this.value < 33 && !$vol_icon.hasClass('low')){
      console.log(1);
      updateVolImage(0, 'low');
    }
```

Above you can see the function called when the slider position is updated, which in-turn calls updateVolImage(); with specific parameters according to the value of the slider.

Here is the function:

```
  function updateVolImage(img_no, className) {
    removeClass();
    $vol_icon.addClass(className);
    prev_class = className;
    var url = makeBackground(vol_images[img_no]);
    $vol_icon.css('background', url);
  }
```

As you can see, it removes the old class it was given (if it already has one) and updates it with the new class which would be either low, medium, or high. This is used to prevent spam updating the background and makes it so it will only update it when a defined threshold is met (< 33 || (>= 33 && < 66) || >= 66).

The makeBackground() function should be easy to understand. It just picks a background image from a list using the img_no passed to the updateVolImage() function and makes it into css.

Then jquery should just update the background with this line: $vol_icon.css('background', url); but that does not happen unfortunately.

I have tried debugging and printing the url variable and everything looks how it is supposed to be. The url is changing and the format looks to be correct.

I think I have rambled on for far too long so thanks guys if you read all of this and decide to help a poor man.

One more thing I should probably mention is that when I inspect element the div that is supposed to change, I can see the background: css flashing as if it is updating it with the same image over and over, but I do not know how that could be happening because when I print the url it changes...

Answer (score 0):

Got something working, I think it was because the url variable had ";" on the end. Also I scrapped using "background" because jquery would add unwanted styling to the front and end if I didnt manually specify it. In the end I used "background-image".

EDIT:
Decided to use sprites to stop image loading lag

https://codepen.io/cryptodescriptor/pen/Gzxxdb

I select the indexes like this:

```
  var sprite_indexes = {
    0 : '-10px -10px',
    1 : '-65px -10px',
    2 : '-120px -10px',
    3 : '-175px -10px'
  };
```